# How to delete whitespaces from a PHP file automatically in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, editor, settings

The question tells everything.
I need to know how to set up my NetBeans to not save whitespaces in a PHP file. I heard this is possible, but I can't find how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove trailing whitespaces on save. To do so, go to Tools->Options->Editor->On Save, select the language you want (or All) and there is an option called "Remove Trailing whitespaces from" with possible values: None, All lines, Modified lines

And next time you save file, it will remove trailing whitespaces.